# How to get average in Java

Tags: java, average

How to get average using functional programming in java?

This is what I tried ...

It seems like its not working at `IntStream.of`
I would like to get average from a specific row of the array

```
 public static void average(List<List<String>> rows){
     IntStream stream = IntStream.of(e -> Integer.parseInt(e.get(2))); 

   
    OptionalDouble obj = stream.average(); 

 
    if (obj.isPresent()) { 
        System.out.println(obj.getAsDouble()); 
    } 
    else { 
        System.out.println("-1"); 
 
    }
 }
```

rows is the array are rows read from an excel file.

Comment: What is `List<List<String>>`? You have a list with a list of strings?

Comment: Not clear what you want the average of... The 9th element of each list? If so, you'll want to map over each list first

Comment: And just saying: be really careful about going for parallel(). That simple call comes with a TON of overhead. You need to process many thousands of objects before it pays of (in terms of latency). With smaller data sets, you are wasting CPU cycles AND end up slower when you use parallel streams.

Answer (score 2):

`Stream.of(elem1, elem2)` creates a stream with the stated elements.

Imagine you have a box with 100 fotos in it.

If you do `Stream.of(box)`, you get a stream of **boxes**, returning 1 box.

What you wanted was a stream of **fotos**. To get that, you want `box.stream()`, not `Stream.of(box)`.

Your next problem then is that you don't seem to understand what reduce does. You need to tell the system how to integrate two results, not just how to get a result.

What you want here isn't reducing in the first place, you want to map a given 'foto' (a List of string in your case) to an integer, which requires not just e.get(), but also an `Integer.parseInt`, and you want `map`, not `reduce`.

Comment: Yeah, I guess the real answer is: this person has no idea what they are doing. They should rather read some good tutorials on streams first...

Comment: Actually, they need `mapToInt` instead of `map`.  And average returns an `OptionalDouble` so you may want to address that tidbit too.

Comment: Yup my fault not sure how to interpret the question ... Its ok solved it..Thank you